# Performance issues using Caliburn Micro and a splash screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, splash-screen, caliburn.micro

I'm currently using Caliburn Micro 3 and have come across an issue related to the transition between the `SplashScreen` and main `ShellView`.

The issue is that the `SplashScreen` has a progress bar, and once DisplayRootViewFor gets called, that progress bar is "blocked" until the root view has fully rendered. My guess is that this is because the `SplashScreen` is running on the UI thread as the same time as the root view is being displayed/rendered.

Is there a way using Caliburn to either run the SplashScreen or DisplayRootView on a separate UI thread? I have a come across this issue before (w/out using Caliburn) and to fix this I was able to run the SplashScreen on a separate Dispatcher thread while the main Dispatcher thread did all the setting up / initializing.

Here's the applicable code (pretty simple).

```
protected override async void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    using (var splash = new SplashViewModel())
    {
        var windowMgr = _container.Resolve<IWindowManager>();
        windowMgr.ShowWindow(splash);

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // long running task 1
        })
        .ContinueWith(t=>
        {
            // long running task 2
        })
        .ContinueWith(t=>
        {
            // long running task 3
        });

        DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Suggestions and ideas are welcome! Thanks

Comment: what prevents you from doing exactly that here as well? create a new Window in a new thread with your SplashViewModel and manually close it after `DisplayRootView`

Comment: @MarkusHütter thanks, I'll go ahead and give that I try. I'm actually new to caliburn, so I wasn't sure if there were any constraints on how "windows" are created